# Different layout directories for themes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-theme

I want my application to have themes. Is it possible to make layout-default, layout-blue, layout-red directories etc in my android application? Or different res directories as res-default, res-blue etc?

Comment: Yes, but this is definitely an open-ended question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make separate layouts for different stylings other than by size or orientation, as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). That gives a pretty full list of the different layouts you can use.

In order to do what you want to do, and have a red layout, a blue layout and other layouts, you would use application themes, which allow you to style all your layouts however you want, as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

First you would create your custom themes in `styles.xml`. These are basic but there's no end to the amount of customisation you can do.

```
<style name="RedTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#ff0000</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#0000ff</item>
</style>
```

Then, we reference them in the `onCreate` method of your activity, before we set the `contentView`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

You could save the chosen theme in `SharedPreferences` and reference it from there, or just manually set a different theme for each `Activity`. Themes can also be set on the `Activity` level in your `Manifest`.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is NO. you can not create your own hierarchy of folder. but according to your question it seems you want to create different layout with different color theme so you can easily create different styles or themes and use them. For more info check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)